# Transformation of dot-product to squared sum of squared distances

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

I am currently trying to understand the derivation of Theorem 3.3 of [this](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gordon_Crippen/publication/225370910_The_theory_and_practice_of_distance_geometry/links/0deec53c16e7102db0000000.pdf) paper (it's on pdf-page 42, or book-page 705).
Equations 3.8 and 3.9 are fine, but I am having troubles with understanding the third transformation of 3.10.
In particular, they seem to say
$$
x_{1j}\cdot x_{1k}=\frac{1}{2}\left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2-d_{jk}^2\right)^2
$$
where $x_{ij}$ is the vector from point $i$ to $j$ and $d_{ij}$ is the distance between these two points.

I can get a similar result by transforming the law of cosine:
\begin{align*}
& &x_{jk}^2 &= x_{1j}^2+x_{1k}^2-2x_{1j}x_{1k}\cos\left(\theta\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & &d_{jk}^2 &= d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - 2x_{1j}x_{1k}\cos\left(\theta\right) \\
\Leftrightarrow & &2x_{1j}x_{1k}\cos\left(\theta\right) &= d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow & &x_{1j}x_{1k} &= \frac{1}{\cos\left(\theta\right)} \frac{1}{2} \left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right) \\
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, I am then still missing the square around the brackets and have a superfluous $\frac{1}{\cos\left(\theta\right)}$ sticking around.
The fraction would of course vanish for parallel vectors, but I don't see why that would be a given.

I could expand the RHS with $\frac{\left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right)}{\left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right)}$, yielding
$$
x_{1j}x_{1k} = \frac{1}{2} \left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\cos\left(\theta\right)\cdot\left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right)}
$$
but why would $\cos\left(\theta\right)\cdot\left(d_{1j}^2+d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2\right) = 1$ hold?

Am I on the right track, or should I maybe try a completely different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square is a mistake in their paper. Consider that

$$
\mathbf{x}_{1j}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{1k} = \|\mathbf{x}_{1j}\|\|\mathbf{x}_{1k}\|\cos\theta = d_{1j}d_{1k} \cos\theta
$$

Thus by the cosine law it follows that

$$
\mathbf{x}_{1j}\cdot\mathbf{x}_{1k} = d_{1j}d_{1k} \cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}(d_{1j}^2 + d_{1k}^2 - d_{jk}^2)
$$

If you look at the next equality after this equation in the paper, then it is clear that they did not take the square in their derivation.

Comment: Great, now it makes sense. Thanks for the help! (Cannot upvote due to my low rep. :-( )